# Google + signin 'signInCallback' not triggered on signInButton load

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

To give sign in with google, I am using Google+ sign button in html as per this link https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button . In the documentation it is mentioned that, after loading the signIn button, the signInCallback will be triggered with authResult, then we can proceed with our function on successful login.In my case, I am having signIn button in say example.com#signIn url only. Once successfully signed in, page will be different say example.com#homePage. **Note : Not having signIn button in any other page**

Similarly on logout, I need to call gapi.auth.signOut() function. This url https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/sign-out says :

> This method must be called after your sign-in button's callback has fired. A new authorization result object is passed to your sign-in callback function, this object will contain the user_signed_out value in its error property. When you detect this value, you can reset your client state and notify your server (if applicable) that the user has signed out.

To achieve this scenario, I am loading page which will render signInButton,then when signincallback get triggered, I am using gapi.auth.signOut(). **But the issue I am facing is, when the page is loaded, sometime the signIncallback is triggered, sometime not getting triggered.**

May I know what the issue could be?

Comment: Is the question not clear? or not useful?

Comment: Hi, I did some workaround. But I don't know is it the right solution. When I am simply changing hash(www.example.com#homePage --> www.example.com#signIn), it never consider that the page renders the button; so no signIncallback is triggered. But when I am changing the complete href with some dummy parameter along with hash(www.example.com#homePage --> www.example.com?dummyValue#signIn),the button renders and triggers the signInCallback.If someone found it is wrong or found some better solution, suggest me.